# How can I speedup IEnumerable<T> database access

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I am using EF6 code first to execute a query that pulls a large amount of data for parallelized GPU processing. The linq query returns an IEnumerable.

```
IEnumerable<DatabaseObject> results = ( from items in _myContext.DbSet
                           select items).Include("Table1").Include("Table2");
```

Now, I need to perform some statistical analysis on the complete set of data, and present the result to the user.

Unfortunately, because of the sheer size of the returned data, just doing a 
`results.ToList()` is taking an extremely long time to complete... and I haven't even begun the parallelized processing of the data as yet!

I there anything that I can do to make this more efficient other than reducing the amount of data being pulled? This is not an option since it is the complete set of data that needs to be processed.

**EDIT 1**

My current code first is as follows:

```
public class Orders
{
    [Key]
    public virtual DateTime ServerTimeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Seller
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public decimal Price
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public decimal Volume
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Table1> Tables1{ get; set; }


    public List<Table2> Table22{ get; set; }
}
```

Although by not using .Include my query speeds up significantly, if I do not use .Include ("Tables1).Include("Tables2") these fields are `null`
in the final result for this query:

```
var result = ( from items in _context.DbOrders
                       select orderbook ).Include("Tables1").Include("Tables2")
```

In my DbContext, I have defined:

```
public DbSet<Orderok> DbOrders { get; set; }
```

If there is a way to force EF6 to populate these tables without the use of .Include, then I'd be very pleased if someone could instruct me.

Comment: Can you work in batches? Like take first 100, start processing, skip 100 take 100, add this data to processing, skip 200 take 100, and so on?

Comment: This could work. What would be better i if I were able to convert the blocks of discrete batches of data into a continuous stream; say a IObservable<T>, cold stream and pipe these to the processing engine in real time. might this be possible? How would it be implemented? I could then process the stream via an adjustable data size window.

Comment: The basic idea that comes into mind is to wrap your query into some kind of iterator, something that implements IEnumerable, and for each Next call it gives you another batch of data

Comment: Or, could I do a foreach loop for straight through processing, then convert this to an IObservable for streaming to the processing engine? Or would this be less efficient?

Comment: The moment foreach request for the first item the whole query will be executed, so that is not going to be different from just ToList

Comment: Could you give an example of how you'd implement your suggestion then?

Comment: Try fetching the data without `Include`, in three separate queries. EF will populate the navigation properties (relationship fixup). Also disable lazy loading.

Comment: Removing the .Include speeds the query up (with or without lazy loading), but the two tables being included return null. EF6 does not automatically populate those unless I explicitly ask it to include them. I would then have to somehow join the three returned data sets back into the original one. This would result in extra processing time. I don't think this would be much relief from the problem at hand.

Comment: You also have to load `Table1` and `Table2` into the context (that's why I said *three queries*). If you do that, EF will populate the navigation properties. But you should avoid triggering lazy loading when you address these properties.

Comment: I am not sure I know how to do this. could you explain with an example? This may be the missing link. I have edited (EDIT 1) my previous post to how you how I currently have the code first implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the main table, `DbOrders` and the child tables separately into the context:

```
_myContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

_myContext.DbOrders.Load();
_myContext.Table1.Load();
_myContext.Table2.Load();
```

Now the context is fully charged with the data you need. I hope you won't run into an out of memory exception (because then the whole approach collapses).

Entity Framework excecutes *relationship fixup*, which means that it populates the navigation properties `DbOrders.Table1` and `DbOrders.Table1`.

Disabling proxy creation has two reasons:

- The materialized objects will be as light-weight as possible
- Lazy loading is disabled, otherwise it would be triggered when you access a navigation property.

Now you can continue working wit the data by accessing the `Local` collection:

```
from entity in _myContext.DbOrders.Local
...
```

You can further try to speed op the process by unmapping all database fields that you don't need. This makes the SQL result sets smaller and the materialized object will be even lighter. To achieve that, maybe you have to create a dedicated context.